# Overlay frame number with ffmpeg starting at 1

Tags: ffmpeg

I managed to encode a video using ffmpeg and to overlay each frame with the frame number using the drawtext filter.

My problem was that using the "text=%{n}" option resulted in the first frame being 0, which is not what I need.

Then I used the code "text=%{expr\:n+1}" and the first frame is now 1 as it should be but it print out 1.000000

Does anyone know a way to remove what comes after the decimal point?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, took me some time to find out the answer. In [the docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Text-expansion) there is

> expr_int_format, eif Evaluate the expression’s value and output as
>   formatted integer.
>
> The first argument is the expression to be evaluated, just as for the
>   expr function. The second argument specifies the output format.
>   Allowed values are ‘x’, ‘X’, ‘d’ and ‘u’. They are treated exactly as
>   in the printf function. The third parameter is optional and sets the
>   number of positions taken by the output. It can be used to add padding
>   with zeros from the left.

I have e.g. `:text=' == %{eif\:33\:x} =='` working fine here. Note that how much escaping (how many backslashes) you need has to do with your environment

So, for your case this does the trick:

```
"text=%{eif\:n+1\:d}"
```

Comment: Did the trick for me - final command was: `ffmpeg -i /path/to/video.mov -qscale:v 3 -vf "drawtext=fontsize=100:fontfile=/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf:text='%{eif\:n+1\:d}':x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000099" /path/to/frames/%d.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

First, separate the video into individual frames, then use [Multiple Image Resizer.NET](http://www.multipleimageresizer.net/) to place the frame numbers into each and every frame. Then, reunite the images into a second video sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter **start_number** and set it to **1**, the full command would look like this:

```
ffmpeg -i /path/to/video.mov -qscale:v 3 -vf "drawtext=fontsize=100:fontfile=/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf: text='%{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000099" /path/to/frames/%d.jpg
```

Refer to the following link for additional info:
[FFmpeg Filters Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext)